# @HostBinding class assignment not respecting CSS :nth-child

Tags: css, angular, ngrx

I'm running into the following issue which I can't think of a way around:

I have a the following application structure:

```
AppComponent (access to Redux store)
   ||
CardStackComponent
   ||
CardComponent (many cards in a stack)
```

each `CardComponent` can have three states: accepted, rejected, or neither, represented by three classes: `card--accepted`, `card--rejected`, and `card--in-stack`.

There are buttons the user can click to accept or reject the topmost `CardComponent`, which bubbles an event up to AppComponent.  AppComponent then uses a reducer to update the value of an accepted and rejected property on the Object that is used to render the `CardComponent`.  In `CardComponent` I have three `@HostBinding` decorators which are used to add/remove classes from the `CardComponent` host element.

```
@HostBinding('class.card--accepted') accepted: boolean = false;
@HostBinding('class.card--rejected') rejected: boolean = false;
@HostBinding('class.card--in-stack') inStack: boolean = true;
```

the classes are being added/removed as expected as I hit the buttons to accept/reject the cards, however, there's one strange issue: To allow the cards to stack, I'm using CSS to position the top three cards absolutely on top of eachother, and hide any others.  This works perfectly and is achieved using `:nth-child`

```
card--in-stack {
    &:nth-child(1) {...}
    &:nth-child(2) {...}
    &:nth-child(3) {...}
    &:nth-child(n+4) {...}
}
```

however, when the top card is accepted, the class `card--in-stack` is removed and the class `card--accepted` is added.  This means that what was the second card in the stack (`card--in-stack:nth-child(2)`) should now be `card--in-stack:nth-child(1)`, the one below it should now be `card--in-stack:nth-child(2)`, and so on.  Inspecting the second card in the stack (the one under the card that was just accepted), it still has the `card--in-stack:nth-child(2)` styles being applied, even through it is the first element on the page with class `card--in-stack`.  Is there a way to get the CSS to respect `:nth-child` when changing classes on a component using the `@HostBinding` decorator?

Comment: I can't imagine this being a `@HostBinding()` issue. Either the class is added or not (you can check that in devtools). If the class is added removed according to `accpeted`, `rejected`, `inStack`, then your issue is a pure CSS issue.

Comment: I'm using devtools, and the classes are being added/removed exactly as expected.  If I have three items on the page, all with the class `card--in-stack`, then hit the accept button, the first item now has class `card--accepted` and the other two have class `card--in-stack`.  Inspecting the second card element to see what styles are being applied, it shows `card--in-stack:nth-child(2) { ... }` which is clearly wrong as the styles for `card--in-stack:nth-child(1) { ... }` should be applied instead.

Comment: Might be some CSS shimming issue. Perhaps the `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` style rewrite does something wrong.

Comment: I've tried this with `ViewEncapsulation` set to `none`, and it still doesn't work.  If I come up with a solution, I'll post it.

Comment: So what I ended up needing to do was remove the DOM associated with the component that represents the card at the top of the stack.  When the card was accepted/deleted, I bubbled the event up, had my service update the data driving that component with `markedForDeletion: true`, which then triggered the component to animate the card, wait half a second, then bubble an event to mark the card data with `accepted: true` or `rejected: true`.  This new state caused the card to remove it's DOM using `this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement);`